# is using MVC and JSON a possible DDOS risk

Tags: ddos

Lets say im using an mvc application and either a create or getDetails function is called in AJAX, to help with page load times.

Someone could easily look through the DOM there and get the URL of where you do your JSON request.

that person could then easily write a little javascript snippet that calls that request 500 times per second and DDoS your site.

Seen as you cannot hide your AJAX / JSON requests from the DOM, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: And what if it's not JSON/AJAX? What if it's a good old HTML form that posts a bunch of key-value pairs?

Comment: I suppose thats a valid point also, but the fact that someone can see not only the url in the DOM, but also the data needed to make the model valid is a worry for me. but then I guess that has always been a security threat.

Comment: Dude, DDOS has absolutely **nothing** to do with neither MVC nor JSON. A user can even spam "empty" requests to your sever. Bah, a malicious user would not even use a browser to do a DDOS attack.

Comment: it should only be a security concern if you didn't know better than putting secrets in something "view-source" reveals.

Comment: Okay, I get that there are plenty of ways to go and take down a site. Thats never in doubt. My worry is that anyone with any intent wouldn't really need to do any hard work to be able to get any model data or similar, as the layout of the request needed is there in AJAX. refreshing a load of times is also a worry, but there is still some groundwork needed to be able to make the model state vaild

Comment: I don't think _valid model states_ are a real concern when executing a DDoS.

Comment: They are to the sense that if you weren't checking your model state, then not only would the request happen, but they could perhaps add a new item to your SQL instance, crashing SQL aswell as the general site

Comment: @LiamHT You are still missing the point. The client side **doesn't** matter. Unless you actually attack yourself by accident (by writing bad JavaScript), happend to me once :D. You have to protect yourself from DDOS on the server side. You are wasting time looking at the client code. Plus if such attack can result in some database altering then you have another security issue on the server side, not really related to DDOS. You should probably limit the call rate to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX is not any more or less dangerous than not using it. That person could easily write little javascript snippet that sends 500 requests per second to a usual web page. That would make the same DDOS effect. You need a different approach to protect your website against DDOS attacks. IP base rate limiting is a fine method of doing that.

Comment: i would argue that ajax makes XSS attacks more viable because it doesn't trigger the page load activity indicator like form submits do, which is why you shouldn't be overly-generous with CORS...

Comment: You don't need to submit any forms. You just need to send requests and you don't even need to wait for any response. Sending thousands of requests and making the server produce all those pages is a DDOS attack.

Comment: i agree, my point was just that ajax is less noticeable to users and thus you're less likely to hear about it or notice it yourself (from the front).

Comment: if you're concerned about a possible DDOS attack, not using ajax won't slow down any attacker with average of knowledge of scripting even for a second. So i think using AJAX should more of a concern for UX than security since one can easily commence an attack by simply refreshing the page hundreds of times by hand.